# Canonical redirect change between app versions

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, canonicalization

I have an iOS app which connects to an API running on a website.

For SEO purposes I want to add a canonical redirect on the website from `www.mysite.org` to just `mysite.org`.

The current version of the app connects to `www.mysite.org/api`. In the new version of the app I will change this path to the new canonical URL of mysite.com.

But that would affect users of the current version of the app.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't affect any users adversely?

Thanks
Sean

Comment: I think so, I'll have to check. Why?

Comment: How does that answer my question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava Why did you delete your comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested the code but something along these lines should work.
Concept is to only force a redirect to root domain if the request doesnt start with api.

So normal pages are redirected and api works on both www and without.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```